# How do I remove a piece of a string using sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a need to replace all occurrences of "StoreId..." that have store numbers with leading zeros with store numbers without leading zero's. I've done it successfully using the below:

```
sed -i '/StoreId=\"0022\"/c\StoreId=\"22\"' $1
```

But doing it like this is just awful as I need a line for each store number and the script will cycle through each sed statement... it just takes forever.

I would like to have a line like this:

StoreId="0343"

And rewrite it like this:

StoreId="343"

(or StoreId="0030" to StoreId="30")

Basically I just want to drop the leading zeroes in one line. I tried reading through the SED manual, but I'm just not smart enough. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like HTML or XML. Can you paste a better sample input and expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to match anything after the leading zeroes.

```
sed -i -r 's/StoreId="0+/StoreId="/' "$1"
```

`0+` matches a sequence of at least 1 `0` characters.

Comment: N.B. this will remove all zeroes and leave an empty string if the ID should be zero. However with GNU sed the command `sed -Ei 's/(StoreId=")0+\B/\1/' file`will only remove leading zeroes.

Comment: @potong Good point, although it's likely in this case that `0` is not a possible store ID. It's common for IDs of things to start at 1.